# Why does the zero ideal in the ring $C(X)$ not have a primary decomposition?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am solving a problem from Atiyah's book on commutative algebra. Let $X$ be an infinite compact Hausdorff space, $C(X)$ the ring of real-valued continuous functions on $X$. We need to prove that in $C(X)$ the zero ideal is not decomposable. The main idea of the proof is to construct a non-zero element of the intersection of primary ideals. This is done as follows. It was proved that any maximal ideal $C(X)$ is a set of all functions equal to zero at a point from $X$. It is also stated that if there is a decomposition of the zero ideal, then each primary ideal is contained in an unique maximal ideal. It is not clear to me how to justify this. I will be glad to any advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $x\in X$ let $M_x:=\{f\in C(X):f(x)=0\}$.

Now let $P_1,\dots,P_n$ be primary ideals and let $x_1,\dots,x_n\in X$ such that $P_i\subseteq M_{x_i}$. As $X$ is infinite there is some point $x\in X$ with $x\ne x_1,\dots,x_n$. $X$ is Hausdorff so there are disjoint open subsets $U,V$ such that $x\in U$ and $x_1,\dots,x_n\in V$. We can extend $U,V$ to a finite open cover of $X$ such that the other open sets do not contain $x,x_1,\dots,x_n$. As $X$ is normal (because it is compact + Hausdorff) there is a partition of unity subordinate to this open cover and thus there are functions $f,g\in C(X)$ such that $f(x)\ne0$ and $f=0$ outside $U$ and similarly $g(x_i)\ne0$ for $i=1,\dots,n$ and $g=0$ outside $V$. Hence $fg=0\in P_1\cap\dots\cap P_n$. By construction $g^m\notin P_i$ for all $m$ and $i=1,\dots,n$, hence $f\in P_1\cap\dots\cap P_n$, i.e. $P_1\cap\dots\cap P_n\ne0$.

Comment: Rereading the question I am not sure if this addresses the actual problem, maybe in this case OP could clarify.